# cm to inch converter, two textboxes multply a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a problem to make a cm to foot/inch converter in C#, this is what a got:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtFoot" runat="server"></asp:textbox>

<asp:textbox id="txtInches" runat="server"></asp:textbox>

<asp:Button id="btnAdd" runat="server" text="Count" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />

<br />

<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>is<asp:Label ID="lblFootAndInches" runat="server"></asp:Label>cm    
<%--I try to get a result "10'1" is 3,939 cm"--%>

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblResult = (txtFoot.Text + "," + txtInches.Text) * 0,39; //I would like to get 10,1 * 0,39 = 3,939 (10 foot and 1 inch)
    lblFootAndInches = txtFoot.Text + "'" + txtInches.Text + '"'; //I'm looking for a result like 10'1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. You'll need too eliminate the issue regarding globalization and regional options (whether the system uses **,** or **.** as a decimal point character, I'd propose changing the code to the following:

```
string separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
txtFoot.Text = txtFoot.Text.Replace(".", separator).Replace(",", separator);
txtInches.Text = txtInches.Text.Replace(".", separator).Replace(",", separator);

Double result = (Double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) * 30.48) + (Double.Parse(txtInches.Text) * 2.54);
lblResult.Text = result.ToString();
lblFootAndInches.Text = string.Format("{0}'{1}\"", txtFoot.Text, txtInches.Text);
```

If you do not need to worry about regional settings, skip first three lines of code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an error on Replace, cannot resolv symbol Replace and the lblResult, Cannot convert source type doubel to target type string, but thx for trying to help

Comment: Sorry for that. Obviously, if you look into my code, you'll see that I've omitted a few .Text properties. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I know no ASP.NET but I think I can handle this code...

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblResult.Text = (Double.Parse(txtFoot.Text + "," + txtInches.Text) * 0.39).ToString();
        lblFootAndInches.Text = txtFoot.Text + "'" + txtInches.Text + "\"";
    }
    catch (FormatException s)
    {
        //Do some exception handling here, like warning the viewer to enter a valid number.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I get an error: Cannot convert source type doubel to target type string.

Comment: That must be because your entered value in either TextBox cannot be converted in double, or is not a valid double string. Try using `double.TryParse()` instead so you can handle the `FormatException` adequately.

Comment: For this you should better use `NumericUpDown` or something equivalent in ASP.NET. I do not know if there is something.

Comment: The TryParse didnt work either, and 39).ToString(); 
 is unexpected token. hmm this wasnt as easy as i thought.

Comment: Fixed. It was your mistake that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int feet = 0;
    int inches = 0;
    
    if (!int.TryParse(txtFoot.Text, out feet)) 
        throw new FormatException(string.Format("{0} is not a valid value", txtFoot.Text));

   if (!int.TryParse(txtInches.Text, out inches))
       throw new FormatException(string.Format("{0} is not a valid value", txtInches.Text));

   double meters = ((double)(string.Format("{0}.{1}", feet, inches)) * .39;
   lblResult.Text = string.Format("{0}", meters);
   lblFootAndInches.Text = string.Format("{0}'{1}\"", feet, inches);
}
```

**Algorithm**

1. You validate that the user entered a int parseable string into each of the `TextBox`es;
2. Build up your string representing the anglo-saxon measurement, then multiply it to get it converted (as you have done in your sample);
3. Display the result in your `Result Label`;
4. Format your result in anglo-saxon unit of measurement for output in the appropriate `TextBox`.

> **Disclaimer**
>
> This code was not compiled but written right off the top of my head. So minor changes might be necessary in order to compile correctly and have the correct expected behaviour.

Does this help?

Comment: Looks good, the only error I get is "((double)(string.": cannot cast expression of type of type string to type double.